# Is there away to show automatically Modal and Update data using setInterval Ajax? CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to create an alert for all users when the time expires.

I have created a condition where if the days, hours and minutes become 0 (zero) then the Modal and `setInterval` shall be triggered.

However, it does not do anything with my current code. The modal on the otherhand does not show automatically, I still need to refresh the page and it does not update as well. Is there a way to achieve this?

View:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>submissions/lock" id="btnexp" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $period['period_id']; ?>" name="period_id">
  <?php if($period['duration']!='0000-00-00 00:00:00'): ?>

          <?php 
              date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
              $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


              $date1 = new DateTime($datetime);
              $date2 = new DateTime($period['duration']);
              $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
              $days = $interval->days;
              $hours = $interval->h;
              $min =  $interval->i;
              // echo $interval->format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s").'<br>';
              // shows the total amount of days (not divided into years, months and days like above)
              $interval->days; 
              $interval->h;
              $interval->i;
              if($days == 0 && $hours == 0 && $min == 0){ 
          ?>


          <script>
            $(function(){
                    
                    //function
                    setInterval(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>submissions/lock',
                            async:false,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data){
                              if (data == 0){
                              $('#myModal').modal('show');   
                              }                       
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                alert('Could not get Data from Database');
                            }
                        });
                    }, 1000);                
            });
          </script> 

                  
          <?php  } ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

Controller: Submissions/Lock

```
    public function lock()
    {

        $this->submission_model->lock();

    }
```

Comment: What exactly does `$this->submission_model->lock()` do? Does it output something? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @brombeer - it's where my model is, the query supposed to be where I update. I did not put it in.the question because it's just the query, I have tried it before and it work with a trigger button.

Answer (score 0):

You should using javascript to do this.

`setInterval` in javascript it is that running every miliseconds you set, but it work only with javascript code, not php.

PHP is server side, JS is client-side.

Maybe it will work for you. Using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to get difference of time.

And set get difference of time run every second with `setInterval` function

If condition is true, then run ajax and open your modal.

```php
<!-- Moment JS Init -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-Dz4zO7p6MrF+VcOD6PUbA08hK1rv0hDv/wGuxSUjImaUYxRyK2gLC6eQWVqyDN9IM1X/kUA8zkykJS/gEVOd3w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<?php if ($period['duration'] != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') : ?>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            //function
            setInterval(function() {
                var currentDate = moment();
                var duration = moment(`<?= $period['duration'] ?>`);
                var diffDays = currentDate.diff(duration, 'days')
                var diffHours = currentDate.diff(duration, 'hours')
                var diffMinutes = currentDate.diff(duration, 'minutes')

                if (diffDays <= 0 && diffHours <= 0 && diffMinutes <= 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: `<?= base_url('submissions/lock') ?>`,
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#myModal').modal('show');
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('Could not get Data from Database');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>

<form action="<?= base_url('submissions/lock'); ?>" id="btnexp" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $period['period_id']; ?>" name="period_id">
</form>
```